# How do I monitor response times with sprint actuator metrics and Telegraf?

Tags: monitoring, spring-boot

We are using micrometer with the statsd flavor in our Spring Boot applications to send metrics to Telegraf for visualization in the Grafana dashboard.

However, I notice that the most valuable metrics I could see in a solution like New Relic or AppDynamics are not visible here.

For example, I can't see my slowest performing HTTP responses. Or get a good idea of the load on our db to discover inefficient queries. All I can see is CPU, disk usage, etc.

Is it possible to configure the Spring Boot - Micrometer - Telegraf stack to be able to collect those types of metrics?